# libgdx : some questions for beginner

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm beginner with libgdx using and I have some questions...

I found lot of tuto and some of them advice that I can use gdx-setup-ui in order to generate my project and others advice I can use gdx-setup for that. What is the best way to proceed ?

Moreover, I generated a project with gdx-setup. After the project's import, I have an error about class imports (I have this error when I launch the desktop project : `Error: Could not find or load main class com.mygdx.defel.desktop.DesktopLauncher`). During the generation, there were no problems.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow [this](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial. It is one of the best around. It will help you set up LibGDX properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some issues with dependances apparently, so I thinks this is a gradle problem but I don't manage to localize the problem